# Editing a text file based on user input error. When the user adds an entry I get the this error - 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

Creating a program where the user can edit entries in a text file (couriers). However, when writing to the file I get the above error and I'm not too sure as to what exactly is going on here.

**Couriers.txt**

```
Ups
Fedex
```

**Couriers.py**

```
CourierList= []

with open('couriers.txt','r+') as file:
    for courier in file:
        CourierList.append(courier.strip())

#Prints the list with the key value#
for i in range(len(CourierList)):
    print (i, end = " ")
    print (CourierList[i])

print("")

UserInput = int(input("Which courier (number) would you like to update: "))
ChangeInput = input("What would you like to change it to?: ")    

CourierList = CourierList[UserInput]=ChangeInput <--- ERROR IS HERE

file.write(CourierList)

file.close()
```

I can get the new entry into the list created, but when writing it back to the file I get the issue.

Thank you for nay help!

Comment: `CourierList = CourierList[UserInput]=ChangeInput` please explain clearly what you think this line is doing.

Comment: Replacing the value by the relevant key

Comment: I don't understand. Please show an example of what you expect CourierList to look like before and after that line is executed.

Comment: Think about what happens when `Couriers.txt` is an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to replace

```
CourierList = CourierList[UserInput]=ChangeInput
```

by

```
CourierList[UserInput] = ChangeInput
```

Then you need this to write your updated list to file line by line:

```
with open('couriers.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in CourierList:
        file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Full code:

```
CourierList = []

with open('couriers.txt', 'r+') as file:
    for courier in file:
        CourierList.append(courier.strip())

for i in range(len(CourierList)):
    print(i, end=" ")
    print(CourierList[i])

print("")

UserInput = int(input("Which courier (number) would you like to update: "))
ChangeInput = input("What would you like to change it to?: ")    

CourierList[UserInput] = ChangeInput

with open('couriers.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in CourierList:
        file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: That's what I did before. I got the error "write() argument must be str, not list"

Comment: I have updated the answer.